# How do I set Windows 10 laptop to power saver mode on battery and high performance on power

Tags: windows-10

When on battery I want all the battery saving features on. When on power I want highest performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the program [Power Scheme Switcher](https://powerschemeswitcher.codeplex.com/) to set the powerplan based on the AC status:

[image]

> **Features**
>
> - Shows the active power plan with an icon and a tool tip in the system try
> - **Automatic management of power scheme depending on the power line AC/battery**

Answer (score 0):

Control Panel | Power Options

It should open to the "Choose or customize a power plan" page.

Choose whichever plan you want to modify then click "Change plan settings".

That opens a view where you can specify different settings for "On battery" and "Plugged in"